# bash: unexpected token 283 in conditional command

Tags: bash

i input command in the bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ a>2 ]];echo $?
```

I get `0`

and another command:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ 3>2 ]];echo $?
```

I get

```
bash: unexpected token 283 in conditional command
bash: syntax error near `3>'
```

Why I get the err ?

How do I use `> <` in the `[[ ]]` ?

I am more curious, in `[[]]` how to use `> <` . `[[ a>2 ]];echo $?` do not add spaces, but `[[ 3 > 2 ]]` must be added space, more curious about the reasons

thank you!

Comment: you have to add whitespace. e.g. `[[ 3 > 2 ]]`, or use `((3>2))` instead.

Comment: What did you expect would happen?

Comment: I am more curious, in `[[]]` how to use `> <` . `[[ a>2 ]];echo $?` do not add spaces, but `[[ 3 > 2 ]]` must be added space, more curious about the reasons

Comment: I think it indeed is worth explaining why `[[ a>3 ]]` doesn't produce an error, what is actually happening and why `[[ 1>3 ]]` does produce this specific error. Or why `[[ "1>3" ]]` doesn't produce an error. Or why is `[[ 1 > 3 ]]` still not the correct way to compare numbers etc => I don't understand the downvotes.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is the error message; where's "283" coming from? I tried it on an old system with bash v2.05b.0 and got "unexpected token 280 in conditional command"; in bash v3.2.57 I got the error with "283", in v4.2.10 and v4.4.12 I got "284". I suspect this'll require a delve into the `bash` source code.

Comment: a>2 starts with a character and bash takes it as a single argument so it returns 0. Same for all numbers, [[ 345 ]] also returns 0. 2>a starts  with a number so bash expects to find all numbers until the next space but finds > and throws error. Could not find the meaning of the number, it was 284 on my tests. See also this https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bash-script-unexpected-operator-4175497349/#post5131119

Answer (score 1):

> As the man page for bash builtins states: "Each operator and operand
>   must be a separate argument."

Also your variable `a` should be `$a`

Here is example :

```
# Returns true
$ a=10;  [[ "$a" -gt 1 ]]; echo "$?"
0

# Returns false  
$ a=10;  [[ "$a" -gt 12 ]]; echo "$?"
1
```

*Following may help you*

**Integer comparison operators**

```
| Operator | Description                 | Example                                                  |
|----------|-----------------------------|----------------------------------------------------------|
| -eq      | Is Equal To                 | if [ $1 -eq 200 ]                                        |
| -ne      | Is Not Equal To             | if [ $1 -ne 1 ]                                          |
| -gt      | Is Greater Than             | if [ $1 -gt 15 ]                                         |
| -ge      | Is Greater Than Or Equal To | if [ $1 -ge 10 ]                                         |
| -lt      | Is Less Than                | if [ $1 -lt 5 ]                                          |
| -le      | Is Less Than Or Equal To    | if [ $1 -le 0 ]                                          |
| ==       | Is Equal To                 | if (( $1 == $2 )) [Note: Used within double parentheses] |
| !=       | Is Not Equal To             | if (( $1 != $2 ))                                        |
| <        | Is Less Than                | if (( $1 < $2 ))                                         |
| <=       | Is Less Than Or Equal To    | if (( $1 <= $2 ))                                        |
| >        | Is Greater Than             | if (( $1 > $2 ))                                         |
| >=       | Is Greater Than Or Equal To | if (( $1 >= $2 ))                                        |
```

**String comparison operators**

```
| Operator | Description                        | Example         | 
|----------|------------------------------------|-----------------| 
| = or ==  | Is Equal To                        | if [ $1 == $2 ] | 
| !=       | Is Not Equal To                    | if [ $1 != $2 ] | 
| >        | Is Greater Than (ASCII comparison) | if [ $1 > $2 ]  | 
| >=       | Is Greater Than Or Equal To        | if [ $1 >= $2 ] | 
| <        | Is Less Than                       | if [ $1 < $2 ]  | 
| <=       | Is Less Than Or Equal To           | if [ $1 <= $2 ] | 
| -n       | Is Not Null                        | if [ -n $1 ]    | 
| -z       | Is Null (Zero Length String)       | if [ -z $1 ]    |
```